# Django 1.10 - App models in a subdirectory not working as expected

Tags: django, django-models

Following the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/) for Django 1.10 with a few small deviations:

- The `polls` app exists in `mysite/apps/polls` and is accessed in the project via `apps.polls`.
- The default `models.py` file has been removed and a new module has been added:

```
    mysite/
    |
    |- apps/
    |  |- polls/
    |  |  |- models/
    |  |  |  |- __init__.py
    |  |  |  |- Question.py
    |  |  |  |- Choice.py
```

`apps/polls/models/__init__.py` is importing both `Question` and `Choice`, and both models are extending from `django.db.models.Model`.

**The issue**
Running `makemigrations` throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mysite/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 742, in __init__
    to._meta.model_name
AttributeError: module 'apps.polls.models.Question' has no attribute '_meta'
```

However, the `Question` model clearly does have a `_meta` attribute, as it is extending from `django.db.models.Model`. It is my understanding that as of Django 1.7, defining `_meta.app_label` is not necessary (in any case, defining `app_label` doesn't work). Any idea what I need to do to be able to use models from a subdirectory without causing additional refactoring throughout my project?

**Additional resources**

- [Entire traceback](http://pastebin.com/sGzWXvta)
- [`apps/polls/models/__init__.py`](http://pastebin.com/kDpyx2pG)
- [`apps/polls/models/Choice.py`](http://pastebin.com/3rVEsE6B)
- [`apps/polls/models/Question.py`](http://pastebin.com/t0m9G2ne)

Comment: It's saying the `Question` _module_ has no attribute `_meta` -- which it hasn't. It seems your naming scheme is leading to some confusion. Btw, you can't import your models into the root package of your app (`apps/polls/__init__.py`).

Comment: @knbk whoops, good catch. So the issue is that, for whatever reason, `Question` is being pick up as a _module_ -- any idea why, or how to resolve this? And yes, that was actually a slight typo - the models are being imported in `apps/polls/models/__init__.py`. I'll edit the post to fix that.

Comment: Can you show the complete traceback, and the files inside `apps/polls/models/`?

Comment: @knbk question updated - see "additional resources" (pastebin, non-expiring)

Comment: This would be more obvious if your naming scheme would differentiate between modules and classes. The usual convention is lowercase for module names, and CamelCase for class names, giving you a `Question` class inside `question.py`, and `from .question import Question`.

Comment: Note that it's not `from .<model> import *`, but `from .<module> import <model>`.

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue. Whoops. Feel free to submit an answer so I can give you free internet points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the `Question` module instead of the `Question` model. You need to change it like this:

```
from django.db import models

from .Question import Question


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Here the first `.Question` refers to the module, and the second `Question` refers to the model. The same holds for the import statements in `apps/polls/models/__init__.py`.

It's a good idea to use a naming scheme that differentiates between modules and classes. This avoids confusion about what you are actually importing. The usual convention is to use lowercase for module names, and CamelCase for class names. That would give you `questions.py` and `class Question(models.Model):`.

```
mysite/
|
|- apps/
|  |- polls/
|  |  |- models/
|  |  |  |- __init__.py
|  |  |  |- question.py
|  |  |  |- choice.py
```

And:

```
# apps/polls/models/choice.py
from django.db import models

from .question import Question


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

By following such a convention, the distinction between the module `question` and the model `Question` is apparent at first sight.